# How to remove dropdown items from a form?

Tags: forms

I am trying to remove two select list items from a form using this code:

```
function module_r_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{     
    if ($form_id == 'forum-node-form') {
        unset($form['edit-taxonomy-forums-und']['#options']['_none']);
        unset($form['edit-taxonomy-forums-und']['#options']['4']);
    }
}
```

The above code is not working. I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of your field is `edit-taxonomy-forums-und` your code should be:

```
unset($form['edit-taxonomy-forums-und'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['4']);
```

Maybe you don't have the correct name of the field. Go to the Manage fields page of your content type (`YOUR_SITE/admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/fields`) and check the name of the field.

[image]

***EDIT:***

If you read the comments in the answer you will see that the problem was the change of `forum_node_form` by `forum-node-form`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. It still does not work. What I am trying to alter is select list from taxonomy_forums. .

Comment: It works when I remove if ($form_id == 'forum-node-form') {} condiion. But how to specify an id the form is using?

Comment: Hi @Dominick i think you have to recheck your $form_id. This should be 'forum_node_form' instead of "'forum-node-form'.

Comment: Yes, you are right visabhishek. I made a mistake. Thank you very much guys.

Comment: Sorry to question your answer, but I would integrate the last 2 comments as a "2nd possibility" (or something like that) ... Because that seems to be the real answer to this question ... no?

Comment: Merci for accepting my advice!